# ATG Formhandler:Need to set some values before calling the handle method

Tags: forms, atg, html-formhandler

My requirement is I have a hidden form from where i am calling a handle method. Along with the handle method I am setting success and error url's as hidden values.

```
    <dsp:form action="blank.jsp" method="post" formid="UNIQUE_FORM_ID">
    <dsp:input bean="FormHandler.commitOrder" type="hidden" value="submit" />
    <dsp:input bean="FormHandler.commitOrderSuccessURL" type="hidden" value="SOME_VALUE" />  
    <dsp:input bean="FormHandler.commitOrderNotReadyURL" type="hidden" value="SOME_VALUE" />  
    </dsp:form>
```

I need to set the `successurl` and `errorUrl` before calling the handle method.

I tried giving priority, but still its not working.

Thanks,
Neenu

Comment: Note that you have to bounce your server after adding `priority="..."` attributes; the normal jsp page compile won't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a snippet of code that I tested and works.

```
<dsp:importbean bean="/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CommitOrderFormHandler"/>

<dsp:form action="blank.jsp" method="post" formid="commitForm">
    <dsp:input bean="CommitOrderFormHandler.commitOrderSuccessURL" type="hidden" value="success.jsp" />  
    <dsp:input bean="CommitOrderFormHandler.commitOrderErrorURL" type="hidden" value="failure.jsp" />  
    <dsp:input id="submitFormInput" bean="CommitOrderFormHandler.commitOrder" type="submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;"/> 
</dsp:form>

<%-- 
    If your form (including the submit button) is hidden,
    then I assume that elsewhere on the page, you have some
    other way to trigger the submission of your hidden form.  
 --%>
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('submitFormInput').click()">Click Me!</button>
```

A few key points here:

1. Make sure to import the form handler you are using.
2. Make sure the form handler you are using has an instance variable and a public getter/setter for each success/error url you are trying to set.
3. You should have a `<dsp:input>` of type="submit" and `bean="<form handler method you are trying to call>`".  If this must be hidden, you can hide it using CSS.
4. In my code example I have included an HTML `<button>` tag to submit the form, but you can replace this with your submission method.

Comment: I found the type="submit" never worked, if I changed to type="hidden", then it works perfectly